How to resolve type cast error with `ArcRendererElement` in Flutter?
I'm working on a Flutter application and encountered a type casting error when using the charts_flutter package. The error occurs when I attempt to cast a List<ArcRendererElement<dynamic>> to List<ArcRendererElement<Object>>?. I suspect the issue may be related to the settings of my pie chart, but I'm unsure what adjustments are needed. Below is the error message and the relevant part of my code.
Error Message:
type 'List<ArcRendererElement<dynamic>>' is not a subtype of type 'List<ArcRendererElement<Object>>?' in type cast

Code Snippet:
import 'package:charts_flutter/flutter.dart' as charts;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ExpenseChart extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<charts.Series> seriesList;
  final bool animate;
  
  const ExpenseChart({Key? key, required this.seriesList, required this.animate}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return charts.PieChart(
      seriesList,
      animate: animate,
      animationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
      defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(
        arcWidth: 12,
        strokeWidthPx: 0,
        arcRendererDecorators: [
          charts.ArcLabelDecorator(
            labelPadding: 0,
            showLeaderLines: false,
            outsideLabelStyleSpec: charts.TextStyleSpec(
              fontSize: 12,
              color: charts.MaterialPalette.white,
            )
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}


Request for Help:
I've looked into the documentation for charts_flutter and tried adjusting the type parameters, but the error persists. Can anyone help me understand what might be causing this error and how to fix it?

Please [edit] your question to show the full traceback

Hello, I edited m code
